# Free marker template: how to assign values having double quotes

Tags: freemarker

Suppose I have a String literal of value :**Hello "Vivek"** and I want to assign this to a value in free marker template. My question is how to do it.

```
<#assign var=" hello "vivek" ">
```

This seems illogical. need some escaping technique in ftl..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can use both `"` and `'` for quoting string literals, the simplest solution is:

`<#assign var='hello "vivek"'>`

However, if you have both those characters inside the string literal, then you have to escape with `\`:

`<#assign var='hello "vivek"\'s dog'>`

or

`<#assign var="hello \"vivek\"'s dog">`

Answer (score 1):

To escape a double quote in freemarker use the backwards slash. See the [documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html) for more information.

So your example would be

```
<#assign var=" \"vivek\" ">
```